# arrow down position in div

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I was wondering how to do a div with a bottom arrow
this is the code I have reached so far :

```
.tooltip-content-m {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: @gray-dark;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: @white;
  width: 180px;
  left: 5px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

and for the bottom arrow :

```
.arrow-down {
  bottom: -27px;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-top: 10px solid @gray-dark; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
}
```

the thing is I want the arrow-down to always be visible no matter how many lines I write in the div , this is not the case in my code 
when I place more content that writes a new line in the box , the arrow-down will no longer appear . How to make it dynamic ?

HTML

```
<span class="tooltip-content-m">
    <span class="tooltip-wrapper">
        <button class="close">x</button>
        <div>---content goes here---</div>
        <div class="arrow-down"></div>
    </span>
</span>
```

**FIDDLE :** https://jsfiddle.net/xzsya7tm/

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you have `display: none;` on your `.tooltip-content-m`. Can you just fiddle it?

Comment: @choz added https://jsfiddle.net/xzsya7tm/

Comment: I can't find anything wrong in your code. The `arrow-down` is always at the bottom of our `tooltip-wrapper`. https://jsfiddle.net/xzsya7tm/3/

Comment: @choz the wrong thing is that I placed div inside span , in my application its causing me issues , in the fiddle it's not .. not sure why there are different behaviors but that was it

Comment: @choz irrelevant question about my code , how can I calculate the arrow height in javascript while I am giving it height:0 ; I want to know the height of the resulting arrow ? any advice ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/xzsya7tm/4/

Comment: divs in spans are invalid HTML...is there a reason why you are using spans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tooltip structure is a little too complex and you don't even need an extra div for the arrow...you can do that with a pseudo-element.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #004;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 180px;
}
.tooltip::after {
  content: '';
  top: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #004;
}
.tooltip .close {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <button class="close">x</button>
  <div>---content goes here---</div>
</div>



<div class="tooltip">
  <button class="close">x</button>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur dolores, iure numquam laborum repellendus ad.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the bottom CSS -20px(instead of -27px).. instead of this your code is working fine.

jsfiddle.net/xzsya7tm/2/

```
.arrow-down {bottom: -20px;...
```